# Should both of these CTEs perform the same?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

If we have a SQL view `VIEW_MYTABLE` with, say, 50 columns.

**Option 1**:

```
with CTE_MYQUERY1 as (
  select [VIEW_MYTABLE].*
  from [VIEW_MYTABLE]
  /*some complex where clause*/
)
```

**Option 2**:

```
with CTE_MYQUERY2 as (
  select [COLUMN_1], [COLUMN_2], [COLUMN_3], ...., [COLUMN_10]
  from [VIEW_MYTABLE]
  /*some complex where clause*/
)
```

As per my understanding, select with columns defined is always faster than the `select *` statement. Note that in this second query I am selecting only 10 of the 50 columns in the view.

I am getting both result as same? Can anyone also let me know how CTE works internally, does it first generate result set and then fed it to the subsequent query (`SELECT` query in my case)?

Comment: Just how much data do you have underlying this query? You'll get lost in statistically useless noise with small data sets.

Comment: I have around 1 million records returned from the view.

Comment: Is option 2 asking for all the columns in the table?

Comment: Sean, no its just fetching 10 columns out of 50 columns in the view

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would expect absolutely no discernible difference in runtimes between these two queries.

However, I would still advocate *against* SELECT *, and not for performance reasons. There is a long-established myth that SELECT * is less efficient because the engine has to go look up the column names in the metadata, but the truth is that there is still a lookup to *validate* the column names you've written, and the additional cost of retrieving the names is going to be unnoticeable by humans regardless of the result set size.

The reasons I advocate against SELECT * is that:

- it is unlikely you need *all* of the columns from the table (or all rows, but that's a different story). If you are pulling back more columns than you need, you are doing unnecessary I/O and perhaps forcing SQL Server to perform a table/clustered index scan when it could have performed a scan on a much skinnier index.
- even if you do need all of the columns, using SELECT * can cause hard-to-detect problems in your code later. What if someone inserts a column into the middle of the table? Drops a column? Adds a column? Renames a column? Some of these will be caught immediately but I've demonstrated cases where this can cause all kinds of hard-to-debug problems.

  - [Bad habits to kick : using SELECT * / omitting the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)

---

As for how CTEs work in general, that's a pretty broad question here. I'd start with these articles:

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/ms190766(v=sql.100)

Comment: Also, can you point me to some article that can explain me how CTE works internally?

Comment: @Ankush I've added some links.

Answer (score 1):

The main way `SELECT *` can hurt performance is by causing the query to waste time retrieving much more data than is actually needed.  But it's the `SELECT` clause in the main part of the query that determines what data is retrieved.*  A (non-recursive) common table expression can be thought of as a sort of one-off view.  Any columns in the CTE that aren't being referenced in the query that uses it will end up effectively being ignored.  Similar to how when you query against a view the engine doesn't necessarily grab every column in the view, just every column you asked for.

My guess is, you're getting the same performance with both CTEs because the query that uses them, which you've left out of the examples, is identical in both cases.  Because of this, the extra columns being referenced in your first option don't end up having any influence on what data is retrieved by the full query.

*Added: For clarity, that's only the case for `SELECT`s. `WHERE` and `JOIN` clauses will affect what columns have to be read wherever they appear.

Comment: Thanks that helps me clearing some of my confusion. I am still wondering how SQL engine does that i.e. how does it parses the query?

Answer (score 0):

Don't return more columns or rows of data to the client than absolutely necessary. This just increases disk I/O on the server and network traffic, both of which hurts performance. In `SELECT` statements, don't use `SELECT *` to return rows, always specify in your `SELECT` statement exactly which columns are needed to be returned for this particular query, and not a column more. In most cases, be sure to include a `WHERE` clause to reduce the number or rows sent to only those rows the clients needs to perform the task immediately at hand.

In my opinion, the big difference will be on your complex `WHERE` clause as is there where main actions take place, indexes involved, etc.

All that said, I believe the 2nd one will perform better on almost all scenarios.

Check this detailed article by [Steve Jones on SQL Central](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/steve_jones/2010/09/01/common-sql-server-mistakes-_2D00_-select-_2A00_/).

Comment: I also have the same understanding, but I am getting my resultset in exactly same time in both the queries. That's why I got little confused :(